# What is the source of this E̶r̶d̶ő̶s̶ quote?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ho.history-overview, erdos

Namely, the following one

> "All problems appeared once in the [American Mathematical] *Monthly*."

I remember reading it several years ago... When I first posed the question, I believed that I had read it somewhere in Krantz' *Mathematical Apocrypha* but according to [Carlo Beenakker](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11260/carlo-beenakker) the quote is nowhere to be found in the said recollection of stories and anecdotes of Krantz. I gather that Erdős might have expressed it in relation with the history of what is nowadays known as the Sylvester-Gallai theorem but it'd be perfectly possible for me to be wrong in this respect too.

I thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: FWIW, you can search the book on Google Book [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=HxpQFHGMfNIC&dq=Mathematical+Apocrypha&source=gbs_navlinks_s) and [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=8mBdvAjk_gQC&dq=Mathematical+Apocrypha&source=gbs_navlinks_s). The keyword "Monthly" didn't give me anything remotely similar to the quote though.

Comment: it's not in Krantz.

Comment: Maybe you read it here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26318/points-on-a-sphere Oh, wait a second....

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Obviously not. Anyway, that must give you an idea of how long I have been trying to remember where I first read this thingy.

Comment: It would be odd for Erdos to have said this in connection with Sylvester-Gallai, as Erdos published that as a problem in the Monthly, not knowing that Sylvester had published it elsewhere decades earlier. It would have made more sense for him to say, all problems in the Monthly once appeared somewhere else.

Comment: Can I edit the question and strike through "Erdős" in the title? Or do you hope that he was also quoted somewhere with that statement?

Comment: @Moritz: Go ahead, please... Since the account of my encounter with this quote has been wrong in every possible detail, no longer can I expect that all of a sudden someone posts a reply saying that in point of fact Mr. So-and-so, in the paper or book X, attributes the quote to Erdős...

Comment: seems like I can't get strike through in the title to work... I thought it would: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: Seems like the option isn't working or something... Let us leave the title as it was: we may try to edit it again later.

Comment: ok html does not work, but unicode will do the trick: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1095/html-tags-in-title-e-g-strike-through

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In [Index to Mathematical Problems, 1980-1984 - Page xi](http://books.google.de/books?id=n-F52zK2UAgC&pg=PR11&dq=%22all%20%20problems%22%20%20%22american%20mathematical%20monthly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n0ZqUrn0JYLWtAa3roDwDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22all%20%20problems%22%20%20%22american%20mathematical%20monthly%22&f=false) by Stanley Rabinowitz this quote is attributed to Léo Sauvé:

> Léo Sauvé, former editor of *Crux Mathematicorum*, an international problems journal, once quipped that it seemed like all problems "had once been published in the *Monthly*"

Comment: I like what I read! Last time I edited my question, I thought it would help a lot if I mentioned some other texts which might contain information leading to the whereabouts of the quote in question. Curiously enough, I had intended to include Stan Rabinowitz's Index as one of the top entries in that list...