# Integer solutions to $x^2 + x + 1 = y^z$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, projective-geometry

In the context of finite projective planes I am interested in the Diophantine equation $\frac{x^3-1}{x-1} = y^z$, which is also written as $x^2 + x + 1 = y^z$, for $z>1$. I stumbled by accident on the case $x=18$, $y=7$, $z=3$. Does anyone know more about integer solutions to this equation?

Comment: I think this question (or variants thereof ) has been asked before on this site. I will try to find some of the questions.

Comment: Look at question 206931 and its answers. The second answer refers to the Nagell-Ljunggren equation, and its solution by Ljunggren- was writing my comment as @GH from MO's comment came in.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Indeed, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution is $x=18$, $y=7$, $z=3$. See my response at [What is prime power of this equation of p?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206931/)

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely take a look at this previous answer of mine:

https://mathoverflow.net/a/251637/1593