# Roots of $x^n-x^{n-1}-\cdots-x-1$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials

It is easy to see that $f(x)=x^n-x^{n-1}-\cdots-x-1$ has only one positive root $\alpha$ which lies in the interval $(1,2)$. But it is claimed that this root is a Pisot number (a.k.a. [PV number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number)), i.e., the other roots are in the open disk $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$. I have tried the following, but I failed. I considered $$P(x)=(x-1)f(x)=x^{n+1}-2x^n+1=x^n(x-2)+1$$ and then I tried to use Rouché's theorem, by picking $g(x)=-x^n(x-2)$ and trying to show that $1<|g(z)|+|P(z)|$ for $|z|=1$. Proving this implies that $P(x)$ has $n$ roots in $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ which demonstrates the claim. But  this inequality fails at $z=1$. Can you give me an idea how one can prove this claim?

Comment: Have you tried to apply Rouche's theorem for $|z|=1+\varepsilon$ with a sufficiently small $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Dear @GHfromMO: I am so thankful for the answer. Juan was right, I just had to consider $|z|$ slightly bigger than one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let $n\geq 2$ be fixed, and let $r\in\mathbb{R}$ be slightly larger than $1$. Then, on the circle $|z|=r$, we have
$$|z^{n+1}+1|\leq r^{n+1}+1<2r^n=|2z^n|,\qquad |z|=r.$$
By Rouché's theorem, it follows that $P(z):=z^{n+1}-2z^n+1$ has the same number of zeros in the open disk $|z|<r$ as $2z^n$ does (zeros are counted with multiplicity). Therefore, $P(z)$ has $n$ roots in the open disk $|z|<r$. This is true for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$ slightly above $1$, hence $P(z)$ has $n$ roots in the closed disk $|z|\leq 1$. One of these roots is $z=1$, and we claim that there is no other root on the circle $|z|=1$. Once we prove this, it follows that $P(z)$ has $n-1$ roots in the open disk $|z|<1$, and the same is true of
$$P(z)/(z-1)=z^n-z^{n-1}-\dots-z-1.$$

So let $|z|=1$ and assume that $P(z)=0$. Then $|z^{n+1}+1|=|2z^n|=2$. By the triangle inequality, this is only possible when $z^{n+1}=1$. However, in that case, $2z^n=z^{n+1}+1=2$, hence $z^n=1$ as well, and we conclude that $z=z^{n+1}/z^n=1/1=1$. Done.

Answer (score 11):

Let's prove the equivalent claim:

> *The only complex solutions to $2z=z^{n+1} +1$ with $|z|\le 1$ are $z={1\over\alpha}$ and $z=1$.*

***Remark:*** The number $\beta:={1\over\alpha}$ is the minimum fixed point of the increasing convex function $\displaystyle g( r):={1+r^{n+1}\over 2} $ on $\mathbb{R}_+$, and as such 
$0<g'(\beta)=(n+1)\beta^n<1$.

$\phantom{y}$

***Proof of claim.*** Assume  $\zeta$ verifies $2\zeta=\zeta^{n+1} +1$ and $|\zeta|=r\le 1.$

***Case 1:*** $r \le \beta$. Then subtracting $2\beta=\beta^{n+1} +1$ we get $$2|\zeta-\beta |= |\zeta^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}|\le |\zeta-\beta|\sum_{k=0}^nr^k\beta^{n-k}\le|\zeta-\beta |(n+1)\beta^n.$$ But $0<(n+1)\beta^n=2g'(\beta)<2$.
So $\zeta=\beta$.

***Case 2:*** $\beta< r \le1$. Then   $$2r=|\zeta^{n+1} +1| \le r^{n+1} +1 \le 2r,$$   so  $r^{n+1} +1 = 2r,$ and in the interval $(\beta,1]$ this forces $r=1$. Hence $|\zeta^{n+1} +1|=2$. So $\zeta^{n+1}=1$ because $|\zeta|\le1$. Then $2\zeta =\zeta^{n+1} +1=2$ and $\zeta=1.$ $\quad\square$

Passing to the reciprocal equation: the only complex solutions to $2x^n=x^{n+1}+1$ with $|x|\ge1$ are $x=\alpha$ and $x=1$, whence your thesis.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to take a look at pages 155-156 of the problems and solutions section of the February 1989 issue of *the American Mathematical Monthly*.

You are going to find there two proofs of the irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the polynomial $$p(x)=x^{n}-x^{n-1}-\cdots-1.$$
The first proof depends crucially on the fact that you wished to establish (which is settled therein via Rouché's theorem along the lines of the above proof by [GH from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11919/gh-from-mo)).

The editorial comment you are to find on page 156 is noteworthy, too: in his paper ["On algebraic equations with all but one root in the interior of the unit circle"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/mana.3210040123), Alfred T. Brauer proved that if $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{n}$ are integers with $a_{1} \geq a_{2} \geq \cdots \geq a_{n} > 0$, then the polynomial
$$x^{n}-a_{1}x^{n-1}-a_{2}x^{n-2}-\cdots-a_{n}$$ has one of its roots in the exterior of the unit circle and all the others in its interior.

Let me conclude this intervention by echoing, once again, [Leo Sauvé](https://mathoverflow.net/a/145824/1593)'s famed remark on the problems and solutions department of *the Monthly*: "it seems like all problems have once been published in *the American Mathematical Monthly*".

Comment: Haha, I liked the last sentence! I also fixed a typo: $a_n$ needs to be positve.

Answer (score 2):

For $P(x)=(1-x)f(x)=(x^{n+1}+1)-2x^n$ you may apply a version of Rouché's theorem or argument principle:

choose a very small arc $a1b$ of the unit circle so that $a$ is above the real line, and $b$ below. Since 1 is a simple root of $P$, $h(z):=P(z)/z^n$ is a diffeomorphism of a neighborhood of 1 and neighborhood of 0. When $z$ goes along a large arc $ab$ of the unit circle, $h(x)=P(x)/x^n=-2+(x+1/x^n)$ stays in the left half-plane and goes from $h(a)$ to $h(b)$. Let $\gamma_0$ be an $h$-preimage of a segment $[h(b),h(a)]$ between $h(b)$ and $h(a)$, it is a small curve near 1 joining $b$ and $a$. Let  $\Gamma$ be a union of the large arc $ab$ of the unit circle and $\gamma_0$. It is a simple contour: for $z$ on the unit circle which is close to 1 but, say, higher then $a$, the directions of $h(z)-h(a),h(a)-h(b)$ are almost the same, so $h(z)$ can not belong to $[h(b),h(a)]$, and for $z$ which is far from 1 the value $h(z)$ is well away from 0, so again $h(z)\notin [h(b),h(a)]$. Then, by the argument principle, $x^n$ and $x^nh(x)=P(x)$ have equally many roots inside $\Gamma$. Therefore $P$ has $n$ roots inside $\Gamma$, and $f$ has either $n-1$ or $n$ roots inside the unit circle (it depends on whether 1 is inside $\Gamma$ or not). That's what you need.